# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous Python error

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing

I need to detect if image is pizelized or not. So i use a python code, that was taken from other stackoverflow post:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

im = Image.open('img/low2.jpg')    
im2 = im.transform(im.size, Image.AFFINE, (1,0,1,0,1,1))
im3 = ImageChops.subtract(im, im2)
im3 = np.asarray(im3)
im3 = np.sum(im3,axis=0)[:-1]
mean = np.mean(im3)

peak_spacing = np.diff([i for i,v in enumerate(im3) if v > mean*2])

mean_spacing = np.mean(peak_spacing)
std_spacing = np.std(peak_spacing)
```

I'm getting this error:

> File "pixelated.py", line 11, in 
>       peak_spacing = np.diff([i for i,v in enumerate(im3) if v > mean*2])
>   ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

How can i fix this? I'm newbie in Python, please give me any idea or help.

Comment: What is `im3.shape`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `v > mean*2` which results in an array of boolean values.

The boolean value of such array is ambiguous for `if`. As the error text advises, you need to tell Python, whether all of values are expected to be `True`:

```
(v > mean * 2).all()
```

or if any of them is enough:

```
(v > mean * 2).any()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `v` is a numpy array. When you're comparing a numpy array with something, a new array of booleans is generated. This means that `v > m*2` generates an array (for example `[True, False, False, ... True]`). It is impossible to get single boolean value from such a list and use it in the `if` expression. So, try to use `np.any(v > m*2)` or `np.all(v > m*2)` depending on your code logic.

Answer (score 0):

Also it seems that this code works well with grayscale images. But fails in the following way with RGB. 
So, try to convert the image to grayscale

```
im = im.convert("L")
```

just after the image initialization